# How to get PyTorch to export the backward pass

Tags: pytorch

I am using PyTorch 2.2 to export a network. Documentation is at: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/export.html

This is the example input:

```
import torch
from torch.export import export

def f(x: torch.Tensor, y: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    a = torch.sin(x)
    b = torch.cos(y)
    return a + b

example_args = (torch.randn(10, 10), torch.randn(10, 10))

exported_program: torch.export.ExportedProgram = export(
    f, args=example_args
)
print(exported_program)
```

This is the example output:

```
ExportedProgram:
    class GraphModule(torch.nn.Module):
        def forward(self, arg0_1: f32[10, 10], arg1_1: f32[10, 10]):
            # code: a = torch.sin(x)
            sin: f32[10, 10] = torch.ops.aten.sin.default(arg0_1);

            # code: b = torch.cos(y)
            cos: f32[10, 10] = torch.ops.aten.cos.default(arg1_1);

            # code: return a + b
            add: f32[10, 10] = torch.ops.aten.add.Tensor(sin, cos);
            return (add,)

    Graph signature: ExportGraphSignature(
        parameters=[],
        buffers=[],
        user_inputs=['arg0_1', 'arg1_1'],
        user_outputs=['add'],
        inputs_to_parameters={},
        inputs_to_buffers={},
        buffers_to_mutate={},
        backward_signature=None,
        assertion_dep_token=None,
    )
    Range constraints: {}
    Equality constraints: []
```

The examples only include the forward pass. How can I get PyTorch to generate the backward pass and include it in the export??